# Contrast chart.js datalabels colors with the background

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular-chart

Using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) qnd [Angular.chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), I have a stacked chart in which I'm using different colors, I want to put the number of each value inside the cart, so I'm making use of the Plugin [**Datalabels**](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/).

The problem is that my chart looks like this:

[image]

Where I have the dark blue I'd like the numbers to be white. But don't know how to achieve this.

This is my code:

```
$scope.Options = {
   ...
   plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            color: '#171d28',
            anchor: 'center',
            align: 'center',
            clamp: true
        }
   }
};
```

I tried putting the colors in an array, like this:

```
$scope.Options = {
   ...
   plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            //The first 2 colors as dark and the third one as white
            color: ['#171d28', '#171d28', '#fff'],
            anchor: 'center',
            align: 'center',
            clamp: true
        }
   }
};
```

But this way it apply the changes by bar! not by the color section.
It says in the datalabels page that you can add functions, but not very sure how: [Link to datalabels page about color](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/options.html#scriptable-options)

Any help is welcome, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are applying the colors across the whole chart when you put them in the `plugins` property. Did you try to set them at the dataset level? https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/getting-started.html#configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer!
based in the code from the link I put in the question.

You need the names of the values given in the Series. This is my *Series* array right now:

```
$scope.Series = ['Low Blue', 'Blue', 'Strong Blue'];
```

We need to add a function to the **datalabels.color**, and in the function we'll indicate how to color the **labels** of the ones corresponding to "Strong Blue":

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
         color: function(context) {
             var index = context.dataIndex;
             var value = context.dataset.data[index];

             //Inside the "dataset" we look for the "labels" we are using
             //and store them in a variable
             var valueWhite = context.dataset.label;

             //We make the condition: if a value of the label is "Strong blue"
             //then we color this label 'white'
             if(valueWhite === 'Strong Blue') {
                 return value = 'white';
             } else {
                 //If it's any other label, we color it 'black'
                 return value = '#000';
             }
         }
}
```

This way all the sections with a Strong blue as background will have color white, and the rest will be black.